# Pandas - calculate within group the maximum value for a minimum within column

Tags: pandas, group-by

I have a large dataframe df. From this dataframe, I want to take within the group defined by its unique values in ['depth','period','direction'] the rows which have the smallest value of 'tension' that gives the maximum value of 'height'. So I want to calculate the minimum amount of tension that gives the maximum height within the specified group.
So from the following dataframe df:

```
depth,height,period,direction,tension,parameter1
8,2.75,4,180,5,16.7
8,3,4,180,10,21.6
8,3,4,180,15,26.6
8,3,4,180,20,31.6
15,2.5,7,45,5,22.8
15,2.5,7,45,10,27.8
15,2.75,7,45,15,32.7
15,3,7,45,20,37.8
22,2.5,7,67.5,5,28.9
22,2.75,7,67.5,10,33.9
22,2.75,7,67.5,15,38.9
22,2.75,7,67.5,20,43.8
```

I want to return a new dataframe df1:

```
depth,height,period,direction,tension,parameter1
8,3,4,180,10,21.6
15,3,7,45,20,37.8
22,2.75,7,67.5,10,33.9
```

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sort `tension` and `height` in ascending and descending order respectively, and then take the first row by groups:

```
(
  df.sort_values('tension')
    .sort_values('height', ascending=False, kind='mergesort')
    .groupby(['depth', 'period', 'direction'])
    .head(1)
)
   depth  height  period  direction  tension  parameter1
1      8    3.00       4      180.0       10        21.6
7     15    3.00       7       45.0       20        37.8
9     22    2.75       7       67.5       10        33.9
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```py
df = df.sort_values(
    by=["depth", "period", "direction", "height", "tension"],
    ascending=[True, True, True, True, False],
)
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=["depth", "period", "direction"], keep="last")
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   depth  height  period  direction  tension  parameter1
1      8    3.00       4      180.0       10        21.6
7     15    3.00       7       45.0       20        37.8
9     22    2.75       7       67.5       10        33.9
```